# How do payment gateways, merchant accounts and credit card payments work from a technical perspective?

Tags: e-commerce, payment-gateway, merchant-account

How do payment gateways, merchant accounts and credit card payments work from a technical perspective? I can't find a good explanations online. An activity diagram would be great.

Comment: Do you mean how they integrate with a website, etc or how the actual systems themselves work on the payment gateway, etc side (i.e. how a payment gateway connects to Mastercard, Visa, etc) ?